# How to make a horizontal ViewPager for the Vuzix Blade?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, vuzix

I'm trying to make a file directory for the Vuzix Blade. Each file should be its own view, and they should scroll horizontally. The Blade's UI has an action menu, and the view in focus should be the target of actions performed by the buttons in the action menu.

There's a photo gallery app that exists for the Blade, and it does what I'd like to do. So it's possible, I just can't figure out how.

I tried a horizontal RecyclerView, but that doesn't work on the Blade. Following a recommendation from someone who might be (or might have been) a developer at Vuzix, I made another attempt using ViewPager2. This, too, doesn't work. (Both the RecyclerView and ViewPager2 work on my Android phone.)

This is the ViewPager2 effort. Again, it works on my phone, but not on the Blade.

https://github.com/pain-strumpet/BladeTemplateVP2

I tried to make a ViewPager (as opposed to using ViewPager2), but I failed. (Android Studio does not like ViewPager at all, I think.)

Does anybody with any experience with the Vuzix Blade have any advice to make this work?

Comment: I have had good luck using ViewPager to get this experience on the Vuzix Blade.  I have never tried ViewPager2.

What does Android Studio not like about your ViewPager?